# Issue with Angular material option select

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I am trying to bind the json data to select option of angular material . But the problem with it is the data is not getting binding and moreover the entire page becomes freezed. I have written the below code.

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
                        <mat-select placeholder="Select region">
                                <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
                                <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let region of list.org" [label]="region.name">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let r of region" [value]="r.name">
                                        {{r.name}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-optgroup>
                        </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

The below is my json data from where i am trying to bind it to select field.

```
[
   {
      "id":"8a80806c6657045f016657c4bb53024c",
      "org":{
         "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
         "name":"Account 1"
      },
      "account":{
         "id":"8a8080126634467a016634a534613852",
         "org":{
            "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
            "name":"Account 1"
         },
         "accountType":"AWS"
      },
      "name":"Name 1"
   },
   {
      "id":"8a80806c6657045f016657c4bb53024c",
      "org":{
         "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
         "name":"Account 1"
      },
      "account":{
         "id":"8a8080126634467a016634a534613852",
         "org":{
            "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
            "name":"Account 1"
         },
         "accountType":"AWS"
      },
      "name":"Name 2"
   },
   {
      "id":"8a80806c6657045f016657c4bb53024c",
      "org":{
         "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
         "name":"Account 2"
      },
      "account":{
         "id":"8a8080126634467a016634a534613852",
         "org":{
            "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
            "name":"Account 2"
         },
         "accountType":"Azure"
      },
      "name":"Name 2"
   },
   {
      "id":"8a80806c6657045f016657c4bb53024c",
      "org":{
         "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
         "name":"Account 3"
      },
      "account":{
         "id":"8a8080126634467a016634a534613852",
         "org":{
            "id":"8a8080a565e5c6f90165e5e908630d86",
            "name":"Account 3"
         },
         "accountType":"Cloud"
      },
      "name":"Name 3"
   }
]
```

Actually i am trying to implement the same which the below stackblitz example demonstrates. But the issue is i am not able to get the data from the json and bind to the mat-select. Can anyone help me in this to resolve the issue.

Actually i am trying to bind the **name and org.name** to the mat-select field.

The error which i am getting is see below:

[image]

Actually i am trying to show the select data in a categorized format which the example demonstrates.

[Example of stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lydmynxmbmq?file=app%2Fselect-optgroup-example.html)

Comment: Can anybody help me o this?

Comment: It's confusing as to what you're trying to accomplish. Which JSON field are you trying to display as the `mat-optgroup` and which should be the `mat-option`? The error you're seeing is due to `list` not being declared in your component.

Comment: org.name as mat-optgroup and name as mat-option

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot read property 'org' of undefined` is happening because the variable `list` is likely not defined in your component. In order for the template to be able to render data using variables, the component must expose the variable.

Also, due to the structure of your JSON data, I don't believe there is a need for two `*ngFor`'s since there is only one `name` property per top-level object. This could be different in your actual use-case of this. Additionally, consider using interfaces for your JSON data as this will make managing your JSON simpler.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9hd7fj)

Comment: Thanks p4r1, itd working fine but if we want to show Account 1 as one group and their corresponding values under it. Like for Account 1 -> Name 1, Name 2 and for Account 2 -> Name 2, and for Account 3 -> Name 3 etc like that. i mean to say all Account 1 values should be under it and all Account 2 values under it and so on. Actually with the example you have shown is perfectly fine but its looking if the same category repeats multiple times. So can you show me how can we achieve this?